# How can I pass event to setState callback function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, setstate

Is it possible in React to pass an external event to the callback function of setState?

Example

```
someFunc(event) { 
    this.setState(
        {
            value: event.target.value
        },
        () => {                 
            this.props.onChange(event);    // <- cannot pass to here                
        }
    );
}
```

EDIT: See accepted solution below by Liam for an excellent answer, 
Here is the specific solution to my problem:

Solution

```
someFunc(event) { 
    event.persist() // <- add this line and event should pass without a problem
    this.setState(
        {
            value: event.target.value
        },
        () => {                 
            this.props.onChange(event);                 
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I found a solution myself but if anyone has a better solution I will mark that as the accepted answer

Comment: *"Can setState callback function receive external parameters?"* All functions work the same in JavaScript, no matter which framework or library you are using. The problem here specifically is how React manages its event objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to extract the values or use `e.persist()`

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

```js
class App extends React.Component {

something = (value) =>{
  {console.log(value, 'coming from child')}
}
  render() {

    return (
      <div >
        <Hello text={this.something} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Hello extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    }
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ value }, () => {
    
      this.props.text(value)
    })
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div style={{ padding: 24 }}>
        <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.value} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' ></div>
```

Or if you meant to pass the value state you can use this.state.value in callback it will work.

```
someFunc(event) { 
    this.setState(
        {
            value: event.target.value
        },
        () => {                 
            this.props.onChange(this.state.value);    // <- this should work                
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Neither solution passes the event for me. Currently only my solution below has worked

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Can this be done for other parameters passed to the function? Or even for other class methods? I'm having difficulty executing a method *after* set state has executed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: WRONG SOLUTION

One solution is to write another function an reference that e.g.

```
updateInput(e) {
    this.setState(
        {
            value: e.target.value
        },
        this.handleUpdate(e)
    );
 }

handleUpdate(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e, this.props.tag);
}
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments below by Felix King, this is not a solution at all. It will run the `handleUpdate` function before the state has been set which defeats the purpose. The real solution is posted above by Liam.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. It calls `this.handleUpdate` **immediately** before the state was updated. It's the same as doing `this.handleUpdate(e);  this.setState(...);`

Comment: Agree with @FelixKling on this one. You would have to return new function from your `handleUpdate` function. Otherwise it executes the function immediately and passes result of the function as callback (in your case `undefined` as it doesn't return anything).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will make an edit to point this out as a "How not to do it" solution in case anyone else stumbles on to it.