# How do I change a property from an array of objects when setting React state?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a dumb question and would appreciate if someone could help. I have an array of objects:

```
weekDays: [
    {label: 'Sun', checked: false},
    {label: 'Mon', checked: false}, 
    {label: 'Tue', checked: false},
    {label: 'Wed', checked: false},
    {label: 'Thu', checked: false},
    {label: 'Fri', checked: false},
    {label: 'Sat', checked: false}]
```

and they will be check boxes. Once a checkbox is clicked I have to check the value that was given to that **input** and change the **checked** value.

This is what I came up with:

```
handleCheckBox = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value); //show value just right
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
      weekDays: previousState.weekDays.map(item => item.label === e.target.value 
        ? Object.assign(item, {checked: !item.checked}) 
        : item)
    }));
```

however this error shows up:  Cannot read property 'value' of null.
even though when I console.log this value it shows the value just right.

Does anyone know how to get by this?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826078/how-can-i-pass-event-to-setstate-callback-function/50826138 and this: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: Where are you using `handleCheckBox`?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using setState with function as a first argument,  you can cache the value that you need:

```
handleCheckBox = (e) => {
console.log(e.target.value); //show value just right
const value = e.target.value; // our cache

this.setState((previousState) => ({
  // now we'll use cached value
  weekDays: previousState.weekDays.map(item => item.label === value 
    ? Object.assign(item, {checked: !item.checked}) 
    : item)
}));
```

Comment: thank you! it worked. Why did I have to cache first??

Comment: @JeffGoes See the event-pooling reference in the comments.

Comment: React uses synthetic events https://reactjs.org/docs/codebase-overview.html#event-system . By this reason your event after synchronous code will be cleared